# Кэширование статики nginx. Не получается нормально настроить кэширование.

Tags: nginx, кэширование, сервер

Часть конфига nginx:

```
location ~* .(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|wmv|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|mp3|wav|zip|tar|gz|rar|7z|swf)$ {
try_files $uri @proxy_backend;
        access_log off;
        expires 7d;
        gzip off;
        root   /home/site/www;
}
```

По идее кэширование включено для статики на 7 дней.
Захожу в Chrome и на вкладке "Network" смотрю первую загрузку страницы. Вся статика пришла с кодом 200 OK. Перезагружаю "F5" страницу, теперь статика пришла с 304 Not Modified. Далее перехожу в какой-нибудь раздел сайта, а потом обратно. Так вот, когда возвращаюсь обратно, статика опять с кодом 200 OK, хотя я здесь был 5 секунд назад. Почему так? Хочется в независимости от того, где ходил по сайту, статика была с 304 Not Modified.

Answer (score 1):

Что показывает заголовок ответа Cache-control в браузере? Попробуйте также проверить сайт инструментом [Pagespeed](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/).